# Form Submit with Different Redirect Location than Action

Tags: php, html, forms, rss, onsubmit

**Problem:**
I have an RSS feed. As some of you may know, RSS feeds do not always update promptly (I'm using FeedBurner) so I'd like to provide the option on my webpage to update the RSS feed. This is a simple process, and I just need to ping an address. The catch is this: I'd like to stay on the initial page, and ideally refresh it.

I've seen some "solutions" around with using hidden iframes, and javascript, Ajax, etc.. 
What I am wondering is if there is ***an elegant way to do this using php/html.***

Below is a flowchart illustrating exactly how I would like the system to function.
[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is the simple form code which I currently have:

```
<form action="http://url.to.ping" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Refresh" />
</form>
```

This is a standard form, performing an action on submit. I require now that the browsers destination (as seen from the user) is a *different* url than that in the action. It is worth noting that the action page is **not** in my domain, and is not part of a domain which I own or have access to.

Thanks!

Comment: AJAX, as you notes, seems like the solution here. What have you tried?

Comment: Thus far I have just tried different html `form` functions: playing around with `onSubmit`, hidden inputs with target urls... Nothing very sophisticated yet. I am prepared to go into AJAX, just was wondering what other options may exist.

Comment: When the user gets directed back to the "on a page" is there any post/get parameters added to say you've just submitted? If there is you could use a piece of PHP to check if it's been submitted, and if it has simply run a file_get_contents of the Ping server.. that would cause Ping server to run - this doesn't rely on Javascript to be enabled in order to run properly

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean. There is no value being passed to the new page. Are you suggesting that I replace my action with the page which I wish to refresh, pass a dummy variable, and if that variable is a certain value on the page loading, use a method to access the ping server? Would this not require an additional refresh for the content to appear on the page, since the server ping would occur after the page has loaded? I would be enthusiastic to look at this method, if you care to elaborate in an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i meant was,

/contactme.php

once they've submitted and come back to the page is there any additional variables like

/contactme.php?thanks=1

basically is there anything to declare they have just submitted and come back to the original page, if so..

You could do;

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['thanks']))
{
    $pingServer = file_get_contents('http://www.the.server.to.ping.com/pingit.php');
    unset($pingServer);
}
?>
```

at the bottom of the page and it'll just hit that page.

This way you are not relying on JavaScript being enabled and the user is not hopped around multiple URLs.

Comment: This looks promising, I will definitely try it. One question: *"at the bottom of the page..."* ... Will this ping the server before loading the feed? Perhaps if I put it above my call to the feedburner feed, the ping will have occurred before the feed loads? Thanks!

Comment: Yes sorry, i meant at the bottom of the page so it did not hang loading the rest of the script if the other server was taking a while to respond, but place it where you feel is best for your application. if you have any issues post the script up and i'll have a look

Comment: Thanks, I'll be in touch shortly. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I have done when I needed the landing page to be different from the processing page is add a JavaScript redirection where one would put their "thanks for filling out my form" material.

So, the code process would be:

1. user fills out form, clicks submit
2. server-side validation and processing.
3. if success then `location.href(URL, 0);` else do error case
4. user is redirected to new URL (your refresh page)

Comment: Would this be a viable method when the action page is not internal to my domain?

Comment: Not unless you have access to the processing code itself. Once you post to the target processor, it pretty much takes over. If you can't change what's going on there, I don't know if/how you can override it.

Comment: O.K.. Well, I don't have access to that page so I'm not sure if this solution will work. I did stumble across a similar algorithm to yours, again if the redirect page was local to my domain. I've updated the question to include the - rather important - point that the page does not belong to me. Thanks for your help!